# How to fix Fontconfig error

Tags: fonts, steam, fontconfig

Whenever Fontconfig is run by an application (in my specific case, Civ V in steam), it outputs this error:

```
Fontconfig error: "/usr/local/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/usr/local/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/usr/local/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
```

Though the application doesn't crash entirely, the video freezes when this error is printed and the audio continues without error.

- Is the Fontconfig error causing the problem?
- How do I fix it?

**Edit:**

The computer is Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit.  I suspect the problem is associated with fontconfig, because the video (Aspyr intro) freezes when this error is printed, exactly when the shift-tab steam community message shows. That text is malformed and bloated instead of inconspicuous. Here is the file created by `steam 2> error.txt`, which I killed after the problem.

```
    rm: cannot remove ‘/home/seth/.steam/steam’: Is a directory
    rm: cannot remove ‘/home/seth/.steam/bin’: Is a directory
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1404163764_client)
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1404163764_client)
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1404163764_client)
    Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
    Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
    Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
    [0705/210154:WARNING:proxy_service.cc(958)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1404163764_client)
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1404163764_client)
    [HTTP Remote Control] HTTP server listening on port 27037.
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1404163764_client)
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1404163764_client)
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1404163764_client)
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1404163764_client)
    Generating new string page texture 2: 48x256, total string texture memory is 49.15 KB
    Generating new string page texture 3: 256x256, total string texture memory is 311.30 KB
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1404163764_client)
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1404163764_client)
    Adding licenses for the following package(s): 0, 11092, 11707, 14631, 28756, 29136
    roaming config store loaded successfully - 716 bytes.
    migrating temporary roaming config store
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1404163764_client)
    Failed to init SteamVR because it isn't installed
    ExecCommandLine: "/home/seth/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam"
    System startup time: 6.84 seconds
    Generating new string page texture 73: 1024x256, total string texture memory is 1.36 MB
    Generating new string page texture 74: 128x256, total string texture memory is 131.07 KB
    Generating new string page texture 75: 128x256, total string texture memory is 1.49 MB
    Generating new string page texture 76: 64x256, total string texture memory is 1.56 MB
    Generating new string page texture 77: 32x256, total string texture memory is 1.59 MB

    (steam:4437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.
    Generating new string page texture 82: 128x256, total string texture memory is 1.72 MB
    Generating new string page texture 83: 384x256, total string texture memory is 2.11 MB
    ExecCommandLine: "/home/seth/.steam/root/ubuntu12_32/steam steam://open/driverhelperready"
    ExecSteamURL: "steam://open/driverhelperready"
    Game update: AppID 8930 "Sid Meier's Civilization V", ProcID 4526, IP 0.0.0.0:0
    ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/seth/.steam/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.

    (steam:4437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

    (steam:4437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.
    ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/seth/.steam/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
    Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 8930
    Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198080162579 [API loaded no]
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(20140630132217_client)
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(1.0_client)
    Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(1.0_client)
    non-double matrix element
    Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
    Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
    [0705/210210:WARNING:proxy_service.cc(958)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
    Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(1.0_client)
```

Comment: Have you tried removing that file? Rename or move it some place else and see if that solves your problem. `mv /usr/local/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf ~`

Comment: I saw that solution, but that file does not exist on the system.  The directory /usr/local/etc exists, but is empty.  Could this be a problem?

Answer (score 4):

```
fc-cache -v | grep -i err
```

will give you an error too at line 78 (for me). What it turned out to be was that the `<matrix>` element in `/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf` has 2 `<name>` elements when it should only have one. Doing:

```
sudo nano "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf"
```

and removing the extra line that reads:

```
<name>pixelsizefixupfactor</name>
```

makes the fc-cache query return no errors any more and when loading steam (and subsequent games) the `Fontconfig error:` lines are no longer present.

Per http://linux.die.net/man/5/fonts-conf I thought we'd need 4 `<double>` elements in the `<matrix>` but it doesn't appear to be necessary.

Comment: that's line 70. also do we leave the two double tag, that would be weird right, only having three elements in a matrix?

Answer (score 2):

Try turning off the steam overlay. Right-click the game in your library, choose "Properties", and uncheck "Enable the Steam Overlay while in-game". This fixed it for me.

Comment: This fixed the issue in Civ V for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Someone mentioned [here](http://forums.pcbsd.org/showthread.php?t=20835) this solution:

> Just remove the fontconfig in the /usr/local/etc/fonts/fonts.conf file

Can you try that?

To find out, what really is causing your video freezing problem do the following:

- Start `steam` in command-line on one terminal.
- Start Civ V in command-line on another terminal. `find` the executable in your Steam directory (`~/.local/share/Steam` on Ubuntu) like this:  `find ~/.local/share/Steam/ -executable -type f | grep -i civ`
- Fun time! Play Civ V until you experience the error. Kill Civ V quickly.
- Look at the output of `steam` and the civ binary and post it here or Google for the Error messages like this: "Error: Term", use the double quotation marks.

Comment: I can't seem to run Civ V alone in the terminal.  When executing with steam open elsewhere, it gives this error `[S_API FAIL] SteamAPI_Init() failed; no appID found.
Either launch the game from Steam, or put the file steam_appid.txt containing the correct appID in your game folder.`  I can't find any steam_appid.txt on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

remove `10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf` from `/etc/fonts/conf.d`
and run `fc-cache -fv` its work for me